# Not stopping program (using shell script)

Tags: linux, shell, suse

I have a binary program named as some thing like "mm.out". This program has some unexpected bugs and the bugs causes it to stop. I want to write a service or shell script to execute my binary again if it stopped unexpectedly. How should I write this program?

Comment: You should debug your program (use a debugger like `gdb`, and set the core dump file limit to a suitable value). You might write a `while` loop inside a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix the program. But if you *really* want this, run it in a loop:

```
while ! mm.out
do
    sleep 5    # Just in case the program dies immediately
done
```

Comment: maybe what he means is to get it to start running once it stops (Automatically)

Comment: @Nunoxic That's exactly what this is doing.

Comment: Are we to assume that only 1 instance of the code is allowed at a given time?

Comment: @Nunoxic Haven't thought of that. I guess so.

Comment: If it is, your code is impeccable. Else, we would need to interface it with `ps <aux?> | grep mm` or something?

Comment: @Nunoxic I'm actually a beginner, I'm sure it's flawed. I would go with `pgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

Let a shell script execute it and wait for a return code, if that code isn't 0 restart the program.